# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near "WHEN"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have doubt about this error ... I can not solve. Could you help me solve it?

```vb
    sql += Chr(13) & " "
    If Not Agrupar = "R" Then
        sql += Chr(13) & " GROUP BY  contas_receber.NumTitulo, contas_receber.AnoTitulo, b.CodParcela, b.NumParcela"
        sql += Chr(13) & "  , contas_receber.DataLancamento, b.DataVencimento , b.ValorParcela, b.ValorAReceber"
        sql += Chr(13) & " , CASE WHEN ISNULL(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome) WHEN ISNULL(func.Nome, forn.NomeFantasia) ELSE cli.NomeFantasia END"
        sql += Chr(13) & " , contas_receber.Historico, b.vRetencao"
        'sql += Chr(13) & " , ISNULL(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome), contas_receber.Historico, b.vRetencao"
        sql += Chr(13) & " , emp.NomeFantasia, cli.Nomefantasia, func.Nome, cli.Nomefantasia, contas_receber.EmNomeFuncionario, contas_receber.EmNomeFornecedor"
        sql += Chr(13) & " , contas_receber.NumFichaServico, contas_receber.PlacaFichaServico, pc.Conta, pc.Descricao"
    End If

    'sql += Chr(13) & " , CASE WHEN contas_receber.EmNomeFuncionario = 1 THEN func.Nome WHEN contas_receber.EmNomeFornecedor = 1 Then forn.NomeFantasia "
    'sql += Chr(13) & " ELSE ISNULL(cli.NomeFantasia,cli.NomeFantasia ) END Cliente"

    sql += Chr(13) & " ORDER BY contas_receber.AnoTitulo, contas_receber.NumTitulo  "
```

Comment: Single quote to comment a line is VB syntax, in c# you should use `//`.

Comment: @laancelot - it is VB code, so the use of the ' is fine ... but I don't think the problem is in the submitted code, which is a group by... what does the code for the WHERE clause look like?

Comment: I see what you mean, carry on...

Comment: ISNULL() will take the first value if it's not NULL, and the second value when the first is NULL. I don't think you realize what the ISNULL() function is intended to do. It appears you might want `WHEN cli.NomeFantasia IS NULL AND func.Nome IS NULL`

Comment: Also, you could use the ampersand (`&`) for string concatenation in VB.NET. While the `+` technically works, it's a lot harder to read with a mix of + and &. A cleaner way, from the perspective of another developer reading the code, is to use a StringBuilder and do StringBuilder.AppendLine("WHERE x = 123") for each "line" of SQL - instead of adding all those Chr(13).

Comment: So how does one debug queries with logic or syntax errors when that code is dynamically generated by an application? You examine the entire query that is executed, not a snippet of the code that generates it.

Comment: @HardCode - goodcall... I missed that the error was for the "when" and was looking for a "where" ... in looking at it closer, i'm not sure what the intention is.

Comment: One more thing I noticed ... the CASE WHEN issue is in a GROUP BY, so it's almost guaranteed the issue is also present in the SELECT part of the query. We really need the entire SQL building statement.

Comment: I strongly recommend writing your query in Management Studio or another query editor, and get it working there, before trying to troubleshoot a query that you're piecing together in application code.

Comment: I wanted to make a condition that if cli.NomeFantasia and func.Nome are null, then keep forn.NomeFantasia. If cli.NomeFantasia and forn.NomeFantasia are null, then keep the func.Nome. If forn.NomeFantasia and func.Nome are null, then keep cli.NomeFantasia. Any suggestions on how to leave it like this?

Comment: `sql += Chr(13) & " , CASE WHEN cli.NomeFantasia IS NULL AND forn.NomeFantasia IS NULL THEN func.Nome"
            sql += Chr(13) & " WHEN func.Nome IS NULL AND forn.NomeFantasia IS NULL THEN cli.NomeFantasia"
            sql += Chr(13) & " WHEN cli.NomeFantasia IS NULL AND func.Nome IS NULL THEN forn.NomeFantasia END"`

Comment: I would urge to to move your queries to a stored procedure instead of munging massive queries together inside your application. This would be the first step in creating a layered application and it is a LOT easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have and error in the nex line:

```
sql += Chr(13) & " , CASE WHEN ISNULL(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome) WHEN ISNULL(func.Nome, forn.NomeFantasia) ELSE cli.NomeFantasia END"
```

There are two `WHEN` and later an `ELSE`, maybe you need to change the last `WHEN` for a `THEN`, or maybe you need to concatenate the two `WHEN` with an operator like `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Also `CASE WHEN ISNULL(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome)` is not an expression that can be _evaluated_. Maybe the OP meant `CASE WHEN COALESCE(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome) IS NULL THEN`

Comment: `sql += Chr(13) & " , CASE WHEN cli.NomeFantasia IS NULL AND forn.NomeFantasia IS NULL THEN func.Nome"

sql += Chr(13) & " WHEN func.Nome IS NULL AND forn.NomeFantasia IS NULL THEN cli.NomeFantasia"

sql += Chr(13) & " WHEN cli.NomeFantasia IS NULL AND func.Nome IS NULL THEN forn.NomeFantasia END"`

Comment: My guess is that entire case expression could be simplified to **coalesce(cli.NomeFantasia, func.Nome, cli.NomeFantasia)**